# 0 Active Nodes when running Hadoop and Yarn in pseudo-distributed mode on CentOS 7

Tags: hadoop, centos7

## Symptoms:

- `sbin/start-dfs.sh` and `sbin/start-yarn.sh` execute without errors, but ***localhost:8088*** shows 0 active nodes.
- ***mapreduce*** jobs fail to connect to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
- Password-less (public key) ***ssh*** is enabled and working.
- ***core-site.xml***, ***hdfs-site.xml***, ***mapred-site.xml***, and ***yarn-site.xml*** are all configured correctly.
- OS is CentOS 7 running on Oracle VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

- Not stated in the tutorial I was following: CentOS needs to be configured to allow a connection to the local machine.
- I edited the file `/etc/hosts` with root permissions.
- I added a line containing my machine's numeric ip address, a space, and then the machine's host name (as configured during the CentOS installation).
- (In my virtual configuration, this was the ip address of the virtual machine's "host-only adapter".)
- I stopped, and then restarted, dfs and yarn.
- I checked ***localhost:8088***: 1 active node.
- My mapreduce jobs now executed successfully.